# "Need of" vs. "need for"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Is "need of religion" grammatically incorrect as opposed to "need for religion"?

Or "need of salt" vs. "need for salt"?

Comment: It would be "He is in need of x", but "I have a need for x."

Comment: @J.M.: I think this could be an answer.

Comment: @J.J.: Ditto for me.

Comment: @Kos: I'd flesh it out if I could, but I'm just going by "ear" here. I don't really know how to justify my answer. :)

Comment: When used as a subject, I think it is usually "need for": *The need for food led them to abandon the small island and strike out across the open ocean in a tiny boat.*

Comment: "Need for speed" is a very famous game to which this question applies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**With "of"**:

- *have need of*: This is very formal usage, though, as simply using "need" would suffice

  > They had need of shelter.
- *in need of*: This is more commonly used in everyday English

  > I am in need of clothing.

**With "for"**:

- *need for*:

  > There is [a] need for discipline in the classroom.

  Using the article "a" in the above example would be superfluous but it may emphasize that specific need. With a qualifier, the article becomes useful, although it can also be done away with, as in:

  > There is [an] urgent need for discipline in the classroom.
- *have a need for*:

  > I have a need for food.

  This usage is awkward, at best, but it is not grammatically incorrect. However, it is more commonly used in the negative

  > I have no need for spiritual enlightenment.

Comment: +1: *Have need of* sounds formal because it is nearly obsolete.

Answer (score 16):

The use of prepositions after need seems to have changed greatly over the last 200 years. Consider the following Google Ngram. Before 1800, the noun *need* took the preposition *of*, over half of its uses occurred in the expression *in need of*, and it did not take an article. When it then started being more widely used as a noun in the mid-1800s, it started taking an article, but at first it still took the preposition *of*. In the early 1900s, *for* started replacing *of*. Nowadays, *need* usually takes *for* except in the expression *in need of*.

[image: Google Ngram]

So I would say that, except for *in need of*, current usage is to use the preposition *for* with *need*. I don't think I can call *need of* incorrect when used in *the need of,* since this was the usage 100 years ago, though. The construction *"We have need of ..."* still sounds better than *"We have need for ..."*, but these are both becoming obsolete; current usage would be *"We have a need for ..."*.

Comment: My misinterpretation of Ngrams have fooled me again. Before 1800, *need* was indeed used as a noun outside the expression *in need of* (although over half the usages were instances of this expression), but it did not take an article: e.g., *"There is great need of ..."* I am changing my answer to address this discovery.

Answer (score 10):

Due to insistence:

I'm merely going by ear here, but the usage that I was accustomed to would have me say "He is in need of (something)" and "I have a need for (something)".