# There is need of developing a holistic approach for the management of persons with visual disabilities

Tags: prepositions

In the above sentence, is it correct to use "of" after need or should it be "for".
Should I use article before "need"

Comment: Oxford Learners Dictionaries has "They identified a need for further training", which seems to fit this. I'm not sure that "of" is wrong, though: it can be used with "need" in some contexts. Also, intuition and this example both suggest "there is a need" rather than "there is need", unless you want to specify different degrees of need (there is need, there is more need). https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/need_2

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Need of" vs. "need for"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/need-of-vs-need-for)